# How to install x86/64 architecture pod on m1

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I know that its been 2 years, but I've tried to install some package dependencies, they weren't working with SPM for some reason. I get this error:

```
in /Users/***/Desktop/Quick-Chat/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRConnectorUtils_846058ed7a2963be49dce7d04c860170.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/anishrangdal/Desktop/Quick-Chat/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture arm64
```

I know it has something to do with me being on an m1 chip, so maybe I cannot use Cocoapods?

Here is the Podfile file that I am using:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Kingfisher'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'ALLoadingView'
```

Comment: Those are just the wrong pods. From the docs *for example, FirebaseCore instead of Firebase/Core and FirebaseFirestore instead of Firebase/Firestore*. See the [Installation Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods). Super easy fix - hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install ffi**

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

**Re-install dependency**

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Follow the [thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10329) for more information

Comment: it is still not working (same error), I feel it is from the package dependency of `FIRAnalyticsConnector`

Answer (score 0):

You should update all Firebase pod to the xcframework version (or latest), then it will have support for simulator in M1 machine. Simulator in M1 will require additional slice in order to run.

More info: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios